# asmx web service method name is not valid

Tags: vb.net, web-services, asmx

Could really use some help here...

I am trying to use an object as a parameter in one of my web methods, but I get the following error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: TestParameter Web Service method name is not valid.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

ASMX Code:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()>
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class TestService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()>
    Public Function TestParameter(ByVal req As TestObject) As String
        Return New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(req)
    End Function

    <WebMethod>
    Public Function TestGetParameter() As String
        Return New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(New TestObject)
    End Function

    Public Class TestObject
        Public var1 As String = String.Empty
        Public var2 As Integer = 1
    End Class

End Class
```

I have already spend hours looking on Google and could not find anything that worked so far :(

I have already added the following in my web.config

```
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
```

And my "test" ajax call:

```
   $(function () {
        debugger;
        request = { "var1": "", "var2": 1 };

        var settings = {
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: "http://server/TestService.asmx/TestParameter",
            method: "POST",
            data: "{ 'req':" + JSON.stringify(request) + "}"
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
```

As you can see, it can hardly be simpler, yet it does not work! What am I doing wrong??

Running on IIS7.5 with windows authentication (no anonymous) and ASP.NET v3.5; Pipeline mode = Classic

Answer (score 0):

Use This Attribute For Method

<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)>